# Ionic2 can't display image under button tag

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to display an image under button tag but it doesn't work. How can i display the image under button tag? Or what can i use instead of button tag? I want to make it clickable whole tag.

```
<ion-content padding="true" class="home">
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
    <div class="list card" >
      <h1 [innerHTML]="item.title.rendered" style="color:#000000;"></h1>
      <div style="margin: 0px; line-height: 250px; background-color: rgb(232, 235, 239); text-align: center;">
        <ion-img style="font-size: 64px; color: rgb(136, 136, 136); vertical-align: middle;" src="https://assets.wired.com/photos/w_600,h_338/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Google_G_Logo-2-f-600x338.png"></ion-img>
      </div>

      <div class="item item-body" id="cameraTabDefaultPage-list-item-container3">
        <div id="cameraTabDefaultPage-markdown6" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
          <p [innerHTML]="item.excerpt.rendered" style="margin-top:0px;color:#000000;"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: you can use simple `<img>` tag with onclick option